# GET with multiple query params

Tags: sql, node.js, express, psql

I currently have an API route: GET `/reports/:reportId/versions/:version` which returns a report when given a `reportId` and `version`.

The psql run behind this endpoint is fairly simple (`$1` is `reportId`, `$2` is `version`):

```
SELECT * FROM reports
WHERE id = $1
AND current_version = $2;
```

My aim is to add an endpoint which can take multiple `reportId`s and their corresponding `version`s.

I have two questions. First, how should I structure my endpoint? I could keep this as a GET and pass query params such as `?id=12345&?id=84775&?version=2&?version=1` or I could make this a POST and pass my ids and versions in the request body.

Second, how could I structure the psql to be able to accept an array of ids along with an array of corresponding versions? This would be much easier if I was only concerned with ids and not versions as I could simply go with `WHERE id = ANY($1)` and have `$1` be my array of ids. My confusion lies in how to search by BOTH id and version.